# C++ iterate unordered_map - compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11

I try to iterate an unordered_map in C++, but it doesn't work.

The map.end() seems not to exist. I don't get what I am doing wrong. According to various examples and my previous work with iterators - end() should exist.

I tried to compile the example below with -std=c++11 and without :/

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned long> map;

    std::vector<std::string> keys;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned long>::iterator it;
    for (it=map.begin(); it != it.end(); ++it){
        keys.push_back(it->first);
    }

    for (unsigned long i=0; i < keys.size();i++){
        std::cout<<keys[i];
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong object to get to `end()`.

Replace `it.end()` with `map.end()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (it=map.begin(); it != it.end(); ++it){
//                        ^^^^  the error is here
```

did you mean:

```
for (it=map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it){    // correct
```

instead?